# Как из foreach вывести вне цикла данные по ключу?

Tags: php, xml, foreach, simplexml

Доброго всем дня.
Есть такая вот табличка:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6"  style="font:normal 14px 'Trebuchet MS';">
<?php 

foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $item )  
{ 

    $tmp=$item->enclosure;
    //print_r($tmp)."<br>";

    print_r($item->title)."<br>";

    print "<tr><td valign='middle'><img class='img_news' src='".$tmp['url']."' height='100'></td><td width='530'><div class='Table_column'><span class='title_news'>".$item->title."</span>

    <span class='text_news'>".mb_substr($item->children('yandex',true), 0, 366, 'utf-8')."[...]</span>
    <br>

    <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showBlock_01()'>
    <span class='link_more' onClick='dark_view_2(\"on\");'>Подробнее...</span>
    </a>    

    </div></td></tr>";
    $i++;
    if($i == 10) break;

}
?>
</table>
```

в примере с заголовком `print_r($item->title)."<br>";` массив выводиться примерно такой:
`SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => данные_01 )
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => данные_02 )
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => данные_03 )`

Решил по кнопке "подробнее", показать полное значение переменной `$item->children('yandex',true)` в модальном окне:

```
<?php
$form_content_01 = "
<div style='height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#ffffff;'>
    <div id='div_th' style='font: normal 14px \"Trebuchet MS\";'>".$item->title."</div>

<img class='img_news' src='".$tmp['url']."' height='100' style=''>
<span class='text_full'>".$item->children('yandex',true)."</span>
</div>";
?>
```

Но вот как поймать ключ массива, не могу понять.
Выводиться, естественно последняя запись по Foreach.
И как-то я запутался.
Вопрос в том, как сделать, что бы "подробнее" выводило именно ту переменную, которая и соответствует ей?

---

UPD: [**здесь рабочий исходник в php-песочнице**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/wAzD31)

Comment: А как вы генерируете HTML модального окна?

Comment: Попробуйте `foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $key=>$item )  ` и по клику 'подробнее...' передавайте `$key` чтоб взять нужный элемент массива'

Comment: @korytoff так вот же - `$form_content_01 = "...`

Comment: @I_CaR это не генерация модального окна, это присвоение переменной строки с HTML

Comment: @korytoff вот это переменную я и вывожу в div, которому меняю `display:block` на `display:none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Первый вариант добавить в цикл генерацию модального окна и передавать его в функцию открытия попапа, в этом случае будет конечно много лишнего `HTML`, зато быстрое решение и удобно отладить:

```
...
foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $key => $item )
...
print "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showBlock_01($key)'>
<div id='modal_" . $key ."' style='height:100%; width:100%; background-color:#ffffff;'>
    <div id='div_th' style='font: normal 14px \"Trebuchet MS\";'>".$item->title."</div>
    <img class='img_news' src='".$tmp['url']."' height='100' style=''>
    <span class='text_full'>".$item->children('yandex',true)."</span>
</div>";
....
```

2) Второй вариант создать отдельный массив и обращаться по индексу, который вы инкрементируете и по которому у вас выход в конце цикла:

```
...
$popupData = array();
$i = 0; // у вас кстати не заметил объявление этой переменой
foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $key => $item )
...
$popupData[$i] = array(
    'title' => $item->title, 
    'text' => $item->children('yandex',true)
);
...
print "...
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='showBlock_01(" . $i . ")'>
..."
...
$i++;
...
```

Comment: Спасибо за оба предложения.
Как-то начал с вашего первого варианта и запутавшись, вышел самостоятельно на второй.
(осталось теперь передать get без перезагрузки страницы)